# display unique rows in view using formula in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-formula

I created a view to display an information. The problem is it will display the duplicate data.
My data for eg are:

```
Name           Age     Gender

Rene Florendo   12     Male
Rene Florendo   12     Male
Ariel Swiss     14     Male
Jeddie Indie    35     Female
```

I want to display only below:

```
Name               Age     Gender

Rene Florendo      12     Male
Ariel Swiss        14     Male
Jeddie Indie       35     Female
```

Any help please on how to display the unique data only.

Answer (score 2):

First possibility :
you should check the properties of columns sorted : disabled "Show multiple values as separate entries"

Second :
there are several documents with the same information

Third:
Use formula @Unique([FieldName]) in each column. Ex : `@Unique(LastName)`

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is kind of way, if you select view property "For ODBC Access: Generate Unique Keys in Index.", view will show only unique rows. It can cause other sort of problems, but if you only need to view the entries that might work.

Answer (score 0):

If all of that information is in one document, then it only works, if each array has the same number of elements. Then you select "Show multiple values as separate values" on each column BUT (and this is important) only sort the FIRST of it.

If your list has to be sorted by two or more of the lines, you have to have a hidden sort- column in front of your visible columns looking like

```
Florendo~Rene
Swiss~Ariel
```

(example if Firstname and Lastname where separate)
Each usage of an additional sorted column (with the property show multiple values...) will result in duplication of entries...

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a standard Notes View, then there's nothing in the view you can use to display only unique values.

There might be something you can do if it's displayed via an xpage, but not as a standard view.

Alternatively if it's displayed via Web Browser you could write some onLoad javascript to detect duplicates and hide the duplicate rows.